# Combined date and time in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am using Gdata library for  my iPhone app and getting the Google events but Google is returning me date as **2014-01-02T13:00:00-06:00**. It's a string.

How can I get the "**2014-01-02**" and "**13:00**" in separate strings?

Thanks

Comment: The NSString documentation has a "Finding Characters and Substrings" section ...

Comment: Of course, a more sensible approach might be to use an NSDateFormatter to create an NSDate, then format that into the styles you want.

Comment: But in any event we'd expect you to try a few things before coming asking for help.

Comment: @HotLicks - Dude i did search on google but others didn't have the same format. 'T' was the confusing part here.

Comment: @MartinR - i know NSString has "Finding Characters and Substrings", i didn't want to find and remove string, i wanted to do it by NSDateFormatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you really want is the string representation:

```
NSString *googleDataString = @"2014-01-02T13:00:00-06:00";
NSArray  *dataTimePair = [googleDataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"T"];
NSString *dateString = dataTimePair[0];
NSString *timeString = dataTimePair[1];
NSArray  *timeParts = [timeString  componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", timeParts[0], timeParts[1]];
NSLog(@"date: %@, time: %@", dateString, timeString);
```

NSLog output:
date: 2014-01-02, time: 13:00

However, I would suggest creating an `NSDate` from the googleDataString and then getting the date and time strings using `NSDateFormatter`. This especially if you are going to use the date/time for anything that displaying.

```
NSString *googleDataString = @"2014-01-02T13:00:00-06:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz"];
NSDate *dateTimeString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:googleDataString];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateTimeString];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateTimeString];

NSLog(@"date: %@, time: %@", dateString, timeString);
```

NSLog output:
date: 2014-01-02, time: 14:00

Note: `NSDate` maintains the date/time in GMT, the date/time is displayed in the local timezone or in the specified timeZone set on the `NSDateFormatter` instance. I am in -05:00 (EST) so the displayed date is one hour later than the google time which is in timeZone -06:00.

Comment: Thanks buddy... NSDateFormatter serves better....